# Calculating the limit $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that $\displaystyle\lim \limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ is $0$ if the degree of $f(x,y)$ is greater than the degree of $g(x,y)$. Here $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$ with no constant term. I have no idea as to how to go about it. If anyone can give a hint it would be great.

I was able to prove it in special cases like $\displaystyle \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ by using AM-GM inequality.But I am unable to get any general method to solve this problem.

Comment: What about like $\frac{xy+y}{y}$?  Should $f$ and $g$ maybe be homogeneous?

Comment: @Gaffney yes thanks for pointing that out forgot ot mention it

Comment: It fails for $\frac{x^2}y$.

Comment: @MartinR Much simpler than my counterexample.

Comment: @GitGud thanks I used to think that it was true so is it true that there is no general theorem regarding limits of this kind in analogy with one variable case?

Comment: @happymath Unfortunately it seems that's the case, but I do use that criteria (with care) to gain intuition about some limits.

Comment: @GitGud and Martin R thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is false, as can be seen by $r(x, y) = \frac{x^2}y$.

For $t \ne 0$ you have $r(0, t) = 0$ and $r(t, t^3) = \frac 1t$, so $r$
does not have a limit at all at $(0,0)$.